# How can I get public ip address in Django with Nginx as http server and gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, reserved-ip-addresses

I want to get public IP address of clients but I just get 127.0.0.1 almost always.
I tested some solution, but no right answer found with my configuration (Django, Nginx and Gunicorn)

Here is my Nginx proxy config.

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should make nginx pass the client's remote address to the upstream server (gunicorn):

```
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://proxy_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   }
}
```

Then you can access the remote addr in the django request's META like this:

```
ip_address = request.META["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]
```

Note that you can use also dict.get to avoid a KeyError while running runserver:

```
ip_address = request.META.get("HTTP_X_REAL_IP")
```

Comment: always returns 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you testing in production, or are you running nginx in the localhost?

Comment: I use a very similar configuration, but I hasn't included the [proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) instruction. Why did you included it? Can you test your configuration without it?